# Selecting all tables with no records

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to display all tables that have zero records.

I tried,

```
select * from user_all_tables where (select count(*) from user_all_tables)=0;
```

But it doesn't seem to work.
How should I go about redesigning this query?
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If all of your tables are analyzed, you can check the column `num_rows` of table `user_tables`.

Otherwise, you will need PL/SQL to make this work. This will output all tables of your **current user** without records (use `all_tables` if you need tables of other users):

```
Set Serveroutput On;

Declare
  cnt PLS_INTEGER;
Begin
  For c In ( Select table_name From user_tables ) Loop
    Execute Immediate 'Select Count(*) From "' || c.table_name || '" where rownum=1'
            Into cnt;
    If( cnt = 0 ) Then
      dbms_output.put_line( c.table_name );
    End If;
  End Loop;
End;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast reply! :-)

Comment: -1 for being a very inefficient method. Avoid using count(*) for determining whether or not a table has records.

Comment: @Rene: I admit that I didn't optimize my solution, as I was under the impression that this is not going to be executed regularly. The OP and some others found this answer useful though, so I am surprised by your down-vote. Never mind, `+1` for your answer...

Comment: FTFY. table names are not always necessarily all uppercase and devoid of spaces; added rownum filter so that query execution will stop as soon as a row is found.

Comment: Ah I wondered what inefficiencies Rene found... but now I see the rownum = 1 predicate was added later. Nice job Jeff. Take a good answer and making it better rather than just downvoting it like Rene. At least Rene provided feedback with the downvote.

Answer (score 3):

You'd have to resort to PL/SQL and issue a select count(*) for every table. Or you can use dbms_xmlgen to do this for you in a tricky way:

```
select table_name
  from ( select table_name
              , extractvalue
                ( dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype('select count(*) c from '|| table_name)
                , '/ROWSET/ROW/C'
                ) cnt
              , rownum to_prevent_predicate_push
           from user_tables
       )
 where cnt = '0'
```

Regards,
Rob.

Comment: Now that's some heavy stuff :) `+1`

Comment: Pwning the newbies like me? ;-)

Comment: Can you explain why the rownum preventing predicate push is needed in the inner query?  I see that removing it throws an error, but I don't understand why.

Comment: If you do an explain plan on the query without the rownum, you'll see that it adds a filter predicate on the line saying INDEX RANGE SCAN on I_OBJ2 saying "EXTRACTVALUE("DBMS_XMLGEN"."GETXMLTYPE"('select count(*) c from'||"O"."NAME"),'/ROWSET/ROW/C')='0')".
Which says the predicate "cnt = '0'" gets pushed to the inner query. Apparently, Oracle cannot handle this dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype function inside a Where-clause - it's undesirable as well, btw - and gives an error. ...

Comment: ... By adding the rownum, the dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype will only execute as part of the select-clause, and only the RESULT of that function appears in the Where-clause of the outer query.

Answer (score 2):

Variation of the accepted answer but using a more efficient method.

```
Declare
  cnt PLS_INTEGER;
Begin
  For c In ( Select table_name From user_tables ) Loop
    begin
       Execute Immediate 'Select 1 From dual where exists (select 1 from ' || c.table_name ||')' Into cnt;
    exception when no_data_found then
      dbms_output.put_line( c.table_name );
    end;  
  End Loop;
End;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select TABLE_NAME
from USER_ALL_TABLES
where NUM_ROWS = 0
```

Comment: This relies on the statistics being accurate. Which can never be 100% true. At least you don't know for sure.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know about num_rows

Comment: @Rob van Wijk: How is that calculated then?. It won't work all the time then?

Comment: The num_rows column is updated when statistics are being gathered for the table. Look at the dbms_stats package for how this is done. Typically this is done once per night/week/month and only when sufficient data has been altered.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is one Fetch-per-table more efficient than Rene's. SELECT INTO requires an Extra Fetch to see if the "TOO_MANY_ROWS" exception should be raised. We can take control of that process with an explicit cursor and NOT doing an unnecessary extra fetch.

```
Declare
  cnt PLS_INTEGER;
  s_Cur Varchar2(255);
  c_Cur Sys_refcursor;
Begin
   For c In ( Select table_name From user_tables ) Loop

      s_Cur := 'Select 1  From dual where exists (select 1 from ' || c.table_name ||')';    

      Open c_Cur For s_cur ;
      Fetch c_cur into cnt;        
      If c_cur%NOTFOUND then 
          dbms_output.put_line( c.table_name );
      end if;

   End Loop;
End;
```

Comment: slightly better would be to select the table name form dual...  that way at least you end up with a list of tables.